# VBA presentations.open : presentation closes after End sub but shouldn't

Tags: vba, powerpoint

my first question here, so apologies if by mistake I violate any customs or phrase my question poorly ;)!

This tiny set of code has been working for 10 years now and suddenly (I guess office update?!) has an issue:

```vb
Sub open_macrotoolbox()

    Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim oPPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation

    Set oPPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    Set oPPTPres=oPPTApp.Presentations.Open("[PATH]\Blank.potm", WithWindow:=msoFalse)

End Sub
```

For 10 years now it opened blank.potm with a hidden window. Why? because in blank-potm I placed a couple of other helper macros, with them being in blank I can just hit STRG+N to access those helpers from any presentation.

Since a few days, blank.potm closes again when "End Sub" is reached. This can be avoided by commenting out the withWindow:msoFalse part. Then it does not close.

Any ideas? Much appreciated!!

Best,
Andreas